# Plotting with axis labels in different location to grid lines in ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, axis-labels

I'm attempting to plot a something called a manhattan plot, a common type of plot in genome-wide association studies (genomics). On the x-axis is position in base pairs and on the y-axis is -log10(p-value) with each point on the plot representing a particular genetic polymorphisms (mutation). Each colour represents a different chromosome.

I have a data frame called `data_geno` with variables `x_pos` containing position along x-axis, `p` with the p-value (used for determining y-axis value) and `chr` which gives the chromosome number (from 1 to 26). The variable `last_bp_vec` literally contains the largest x-axis position of each chromosome.

From the following code:

```
ggplotcmd <- ggplot(data_geno, aes(x=x_pos, y=-log10(p), color=chr)) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = last_bp_vec,minor_breaks=NULL,labels=seq(26)) + 
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=-log10(5e-08))) + 
    geom_point(shape=20, size = 1) + 
    geom_point(data=data_imp,color="black",shape=4) + 
    xlab("") + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=0)) +  
    scale_color_manual(values=c("deeppink2", "orange", "green2", "blue", "yellow", 
        "purple",  "magenta", "darkgreen", "gold", "firebrick", "yellowgreen", "red", 
        "black", "turquoise3", "tomato", "darkblue", "chocolate", "violet", "slategray4", 
        "OrangeRed", "darkblue", "deeppink", "aquamarine3", "steelblue1", "mediumorchid", 
        "yellowgreen")) + 
    ggtitle(man_title)
```

I have produce a plot like this:

[image: Manhattan plot]

All I wish to do is shift the x-axis label positions to the middle of their respective bunch of points (so I don't rely on a legend), i.e. I wish the "1" to sit under the middle position of the magenta coloured points and "2" to sit under the middle of the orange points etc... The x-axis ticks and grid lines are in the correct position and I wish to keep those there.

I'm aware of the solution using `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=VALUE))` but this doesn't work as it shifts each label by the same amount and since chromosomes are different sizes, I need each label shifted by a different amount.

I'm still learning to use ggplot and (more generally) R, so please do correct me if I'm doing something horribly wrong or if there's a much simpler way to achieve what I'm attempting to do!

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: You can set the `labels` of `scale_x_continuous` to different values than `breaks` (be careful, obviously). If you use your minor gridlines as major ones, you can probably get it to look pretty normal.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've done a pretty extensive search and I cannot find an example where someone has set labels at different positions to the breaks. Would you be able to show an example of how to do this?

Comment: Not different positions, different numbers, e.g. set `breaks = seq(.5, 22.5, by = 1), labels = 1:23`.

Comment: Thanks again for the response. If I change the breaks the major gridlines move too, except I wanted to keep them where they are. The only solution I've worked out so far is to switch off grid lines and plot my own "custom" grid lines. I was wondering whether I'm missing something or are gridlines inextricably tied to tick marks and labels.

Comment: They are tied, thus why I suggested using the minor ones as major. You can set thickness with `theme`.